# Remove &nbsp; from NSString,Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, special-characters

I have string that i get from server and comes with whitecaps and `&nbsp;`. I try to remove this `&nbsp;` but didn't succeeded. Is there Anyone that have the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is the string you are getting from the server? How are you trying to remove it?

Comment: 1. What is the question othan a survey of how many others have a similar vaguly described problem. 2. Where is the code you need help with? 3. What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Provide your code, what you have tried?

Comment: `NSString method: `- stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`.

Answer (score 5):

If the `string` coming from server have constant "&nbsp" string and you want to remove that you can use.

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;"
                                  withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to replace all html characters:

```
    let str = "Hello&nbsp;World"

    let options:[NSObject : AnyObject] = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding]

    let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

    let strAttr = NSAttributedString(data: data!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)

    let strFinal = strAttr!.string
```

Comment: did you import Foundation?

Comment: `let strAttr = NSAttributedString(data: data!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)` reports "nwi_state: registration failed (1000000)".

Comment: Try this on a real app, not on the playground. If you are getting an error, post here the string you are trying to convert.

Comment: don't work this is what i get from server:

A8\U00a0quattro\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0\U00a0[02]

Comment: I copy and pasted the code from the answer into the Swift Playground. The console output was: "nwi_state: registration failed (1000000)".

Comment: what you are posting here, "A8\U00a0quattro", are not &nbsp, are unicode encoded spaces. You need a completly different answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift**

```
let result2 = yourStringName.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&nbsp;", withString:"")
println(result2)
```

**objective-C**

use <kbd>Shurthi</kbd> Answer or

```
NSString *finalStr = [yourStringName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"finalStr ==%@", finalStr);
```

Comment: @zaph - sry my senior I missed the `;` , now I added